# The easiest way to achieve real push notifications on a hybrid mobile app

Tags: cordova, react-native, push-notification, onesignal, pubnub

I know my question looks quite common and not specific but I will do my best to explain by experience on it so far and hopefully I will get some useful feedback.

I am working on a project which main purpose is to send real time notifications to a mobile device from a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ after a specific event occurred on the Raspberry. We had a successful start but when building the mobile application using [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) and [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/) as a programming language we didn't expect certain things which happened on a later stage. This is how the bigger picture looks like: [Architecture overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zepiP.jpg)

As for a beginning, I must say that we didn't have a real **Push Notifications** platform (like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) or [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/)). What we were doing was to take advantage of a [SignalR Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server) hosted in Azure to which, both, the mobile application and the Raspberry code (python) were connecting to. So every time the mobile app was receive a **SignalR** event we were firing [Cordova local notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) so we were able to simulate real life. As you may already suppose, this was not a consistent solution. We had number of issues when:

1. The app stays for more than 10 minutes in background on IOS
2. The app is closed/killed
3. The instance on Azure (hosting the hub) goes to hibernate state
4. We had a need for a support community regarding cordova/phonegap issues

So, for that reason, I decided to reach out for the World to ask for an opinion of how to re-structure this solution with the push notifications. Basically, they are the most important thing here. I want them to behave as all for all the other apps which send you PNs even if the app was on background for quite some time or it was even killed.

I am on my way to writing specific requirements for a professional who can implement the mobile application and I would be really happy if you can give me a direction here. I am now mostly focused on React Native

Comment: You tagged this ```react-native```. Are you using React Native?

Answer (score 0):

PubNub can provide the instant connection, message delivery, and device control required in your system. I recommend you use the Python or C SDK on the Raspberry Pi. This way, your Raspberry Pi can send a secure message at any time that will trigger a push notification in a mobile app.

[image]

- There is a guide for [developing the mobile application with React
  Native and Push Notifications](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications-ios-android/?devrel_so=the-easiest-way-to-achieve-real-push-notifications-on-a-hybrid-mobile-app) on the PubNub Blog.
- There are also
  several guides for developing an [IoT signaling application using
  Raspberry Pi and PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/create-an-iot-twitter-bot-in-5-easy-steps/?devrel_so=the-easiest-way-to-achieve-real-push-notifications-on-a-hybrid-mobile-app).